# Passing data from a View to a Controller alongside a Form's values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Part of the website I'm doing (a simple turn-per-turn browser game) requires me to pass data from a View to a controller (passing an Foreign Key from a DropDownList and another integer value in the view as argument to the controller). Next the controller uses these values to pass execution to another controller.

My problem is that I have troubles figuring out how MVC returns the data inside my view and bundle inside types and use them as parameters. I know I could use an action link to point to my next controller but I do not know how to retrieve the selected value in the DropDownList. That or use an Input Button but then I do not know what or how the values are returned.

Do tell me if you require extra explanation or anything is confusing.

Here is my code :

The view in Razor, receiving a view model, defined below.

```
@model BattleForLurnia_MVC.Controllers.ChooseCharacterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ChooseCharacter";
}

<h2>Choose Your Character</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Choose your fighter !</legend>

    <div class="display-label">Your characters :</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CharactersList", String.Empty)
    </div>


    @* Here is the part that returns the values, either an ActionLink or 
       an Input button.*@

</fieldset>
```

---

My ViewModel passed to the View

```
public class ChooseCharacterViewModel
{
    Battle_For_LurniaEntities db = new Battle_For_LurniaEntities();

    public Player player { get; set; }
    public Character targetCharacter { get; set; }

    public ChooseCharacterViewModel(string playerUsername, Character opponent)
    {
        player = db.Players.Single(plr => plr.Username == playerUsername);
        targetCharacter = opponent;
    }

    public ChooseCharacterViewModel(){}
}
```

---

The controler that sends the View

```
    public ActionResult ChooseCharacter(int targetCharacter_ID)
    {
        Character targetChar = db.Characters.Single(chr => chr.ID_Character == targetCharacter_ID);

        ChooseCharacterViewModel chooseCharacter = new ChooseCharacterViewModel(Session["Username"].ToString(), targetChar);

        // Using LINQ to get characters owned by the current player. Fuckyeah.jpg =D
        IEnumerable<Character> blabla = from VAR in db.Characters
                                        where VAR.FK_Player_ID == chooseCharacter.player.ID_Player
                                        select VAR;

        ViewBag.CharactersList = new SelectList(blabla, "ID_Character", "Name");
        return View(chooseCharacter);
    }
```

---

And finally the controller that receives the data in my view and sends another view.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChooseCharacter(int FK_Character_ID, Character targetCharacter)
    {
        Character sourceCharacter = db.Characters.Single(chr => chr.ID_Character == FK_Character_ID);

        return RedirectToAction("Fight", new {SourceCharacter = sourceCharacter, TargetCharacter = targetCharacter});
    }
```

Comment: Quick side note. View model should not contain data access logic. Its purpose is to represent the state of UI or form submission.  @sajoshi directions seems ok and should give you what you want. PS: love the name of your jpeg file within comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewModel, create three properties

1. SelectedId
2. ListOfItems
3. OtherItemsThatYouNeedToGetBackAtController

When you POST back to your controller using a Html.BeginForm, the model will be passed back. For getting the Selected DropDown Value, change the syntax as below:

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.ListofItems))

For the OtherItemsThatYouNeedToGetBackAtController, You can use 
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.OtherItemsThatYouNeedToGetBackAtController)